# Excluding Namespaces in XML results

Tags: xslt

I am trying to figure out how best I can process the XML file below so the resulting XML file excludes namespace declarations.

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/">
  <b:title>Book Title</b:title>
  <p:number>page001</p:number>
  <p:number>page002</p:number>
  <p:number>page001</p:number>
  <p:number>page002</p:number>
</page>
```

**Current XSL File**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:b="http://book.com/" 
xmlns:p="http://page.com/"
>

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

 <xsl:template match="resource">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="b:title" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="p:number" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b:title">
   <title exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </title>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p:number">
   <page exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </page>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output**

```
  <title xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">Book Title</title>
  <page xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">page001</page>
  <page xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">page002</page>
  <page xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">page001</page>
  <page xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">page002</page>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <title>Book Title</title>
  <page>page001</page>
  <page>page002</page>
  <page>page001</page>
  <page>page002</page>
```

Comment: :D Just found my solution ->>>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689443/problem-with-xslt-and-namespaces

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, easy, and simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='number']">
  <page>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </page>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<page xmlns:b="http://book.com/" xmlns:p="http://page.com/">
    <b:title>Book Title</b:title>
    <p:number>page001</p:number>
    <p:number>page002</p:number>
    <p:number>page001</p:number>
    <p:number>page002</p:number>
</page>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<page>
    <title>Book Title</title>
    <page>page001</page>
    <page>page002</page>
    <page>page001</page>
    <page>page002</page>
</page>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Use of the [`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element) instruction** to create (not copy!) a new element with name that is the [**`local-name()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name) of the matched element.
2. **A template matching elements with `local-name()` `number`** to "rename" them to `page`

Answer (score 6):

Use the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

In your case, something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:b="http://book.com/" 
xmlns:p="http://page.com/"
exclude-result-prefixes="b p"
>

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

 <xsl:template match="resource">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="b:title" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="p:number" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b:title">
   <title>       
     <xsl:value-of select="." />       
   </title>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p:number">       
   <page>
     <xsl:value-of select="." />       
   </page>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```